# Sequelize Migration Add Array Column

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to add a column via migration to a particular table.
The goal is to add a column type of an array that include enum values

***1 Attempt:***

```
await queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Locations',
      'tags',
      {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.ENUM({
          values: ['Competitor', 'Multi Location', 'Duplicate']
      })),
      }
    );
```

***Result:*** `ERROR: type "public.enum_Locations_tags[]" does not exist`

***2 Attempt:***

```
await queryInterface.sequelize.query("CREATE TYPE enum_Locations_tags AS ENUM ('Competitor', 'Multi Location', 'Duplicate');");
    await queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Locations',
      'tags',
      {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.ENUM({
          values: ['Competitor', 'Multi Location', 'Duplicate']
      })),
      }
    );
```

***Result:*** `ERROR: type "public.enum_Locations_tags[]" does not exist`

Any idea how to solve this
Thanks in advance!

Comment: i would recommend to open database in command line and look at the names. Sometimes, ORM name tables with double quotes, for ex : instead of creating table `user` it will create table with `"user"`

Comment: did you ever find the answer?

Comment: I used raw query for this instead of this above method

Answer (score 1):

```js
await queryInterface.addColumn('event-action-item', 'actionTags', {

  type: Sequelize.DataTypes.ARRAY(Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING),

  defaultValue: [],

});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.